# Negative scenario for service post method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have post method in Service.
If student age > 18, then I want to save object.
If age < 18 .. I don't want to save object.

How can I pass this information to Controller (ResponseEntity) to throw 401?

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
  public Student save(Student Student) {

    //some logic

    if (studentAge > 20) {
      student.setId(null);
      return studentRepository.save(student);
    } else {
      //what are the good practices here?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about return null? And check for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't return 401 on this case. 401 indicates authentication issue. 400 seems more suitable.

Second thing, the service should not handle error codes - this should be handled by the controller. the service should indicate there's a problem, and the layer using it should decide what to do.
It can either be by returning null student or throwing some dedicated exception.
A cleaner approach can be to do it outside of the save method - to have a validator with `boolean isValid()` method that will be called before saving

Comment: I decided to throw dedicated (custom) exception in service and added 'throws' of this exception to signature of controller method, then my global exception handler takes care of the exception and returns 400, it works like a charm!